# Jquery Each function, if statement doesn't work

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each

```
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        function changecolor() 
        {


            $('li').each(function() 
            {
                var sval = $(this).text();
                //alert(sval);
                if (sval == "Rose") 
                {
                    alert(sval);
                    $(item).css('backgroundcolor', 'red');
                }

            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Select your fraglance : 
    <ul>
        <li>Rose</li>
        <li>White Jasmine</li>
        <li>Yellow Sunflower</li>
        <li>Pink Lotus</li>
        <li>White Daisy</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="text"  onclick="changecolor()">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`item` is not defined somewhere.

Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pepMJ/

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use `background-color` since that's the CSS name.

```
$(item).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is item defined in the js? May be its a mistake. Try this

```
<script type="text/jscript">
        function changecolor() 
        {


            $('li').each(function() 
            {
                var sval = $(this).text();
                //alert(sval);
                if (sval == "Rose") 
                {
                    alert(sval);
                    $(this).css('backgroundcolor', 'red');
                }

            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot item inside your .each

```
$('li').each(function(i, item)
```